# Reading TIFF in Python and Matplotlib using GDAL

Tags: python, matplotlib, gdal

I'm trying to display a grayscale TIFF file using Python and MatPlotLib,

So far I have read the file this:

```
import scipy as N
import gdal
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot

try:
    tif = gdal.Open('filename.tif')
    tifArray = tif.ReadAsArray()
except:
    print 'The file does not exist.'
    sys.exit(0)

band1 = tif.GetRasterBand(1)
band2 = tif.GetRasterBand(2)
band3 = tif.GetRasterBand(3)

band1Array = band1.ReadAsArray()
band2Array = band2.ReadAsArray()
band3Array = band3.ReadAsArray()
```

But then I don't know what else should I do... I'm so clueless.
Anyone would help me in this?

Comment: How are you not getting any import error for GDAL?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Once you processed your file into a 2 Array, you could use ANY function in matplotlib that plots 2D arrays, e.g. cmap, imshow etc.

Here is the output with the [marbles example](http://www.fileformat.info/format/tiff/sample/index.htm)

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img=mpimg.imread('MARBLES.TIF ')
imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
```

Here is what you get if you view only band3  of the image:

```
imgplot2 = plt.imshow(band3Array)
plt.show()
```

[image: band3 of marbles]

Look further into image viewing in MPL and 2D array functions...